# Is it possible to add a subtitle by Plots.jl?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Consider the following plot:
[image]

I want to put the "Analysed data range: ... 2020-01-01" as a subtitle with a different attribute, i.e., a smaller font. Is it possible? As of now, I have used the following keyword argument in the `plot` function:

```
title="Cepstral Coefficients\nAnalysed data range: $(startdt) to $(enddt)"
```

So, it is separated using the `\n` string literal.

Comment: I remember asking this long time ago, and at that time it wasn't possible..

Comment: @Antonello, I didn't find similar questions, so I asked it. I wish we would have the ability to define subtitles.

Comment: unfortunately there is no "subtitle" attribute you can set, but what I usually do in these kinds of cases is use the `annotate` functionality (which allows you to specify font size, family, color, etc. independently of whatever the title itself is set to).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `using LaTeXStrings` with the following formatting:

```
plot(rand(3), title=LaTeXString("Main title 1\n\$^\\textrm{subtitle\\ of\\ plot}\$"))
```

Note that superscript is available only in math mode hence more complicated formatting of spaces.

[image]